# Best way to store data(table) and easy acces to represent it

Tags: python, html, json, django, templates

I'm working with the django framework and I found a way to store the data that I recieved by a RPC call.  This data follow the JSON format:

```
{"header":["data_enviament","nom_auditor","matricula","bastidor"],"data":[{"data_enviament":"05/1/2014","nom_auditor":"Brutus Brutus, Marc","matricula":"1234FRX","bastidor":"192891478kjhda"},{"data_enviament":"05/2/2014","nom_auditor":"Pepito Rudolf, Margarita","matricula":"2234FRX","bastidor":"192891478kjhda"},{"data_enviament":"05/5/2014","nom_auditor":"Patrick Linda, Judith","matricula":"5234FRX","bastidor":"192891478kjhda"}],"count":2}
```

And I store this data into a matrix( at the controller point ), the code is:

```
for i in range(len(tabla['header'])):
        array[0][i] = tabla['header'][i]


    x = 1
    for data in tabla['data']:
        for i in range(len(tabla['header'])):
            array[x][i] = data[array[0][i]]
        x = x + 1
```

Then I parse this data by the render function to the template and represent into a html table.
I'm doing fine or there are maybe another way to do it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform the data into a list of lists keeping the order of the items according to the header.

Demo from the shell:

```
>>> from django.template import Template, Context
>>> data = {"header":["data_enviament","nom_auditor","matricula","bastidor"],"data":[{"data_enviament":"05/1/2014","nom_auditor":"Brutus Brutus, Marc","matricula":"1234FRX","bastidor":"192891478kjhda"},{"data_enviament":"05/2/2014","nom_auditor":"Pepito Rudolf, Margarita","matricula":"2234FRX","bastidor":"192891478kjhda"},{"data_enviament":"05/5/2014","nom_auditor":"Patrick Linda, Judith","matricula":"5234FRX","bastidor":"192891478kjhda"}],"count":2}
>>>
>>> data = [[item[header] for header in data['header']] for item in data['data']]
>>> c = Context({'data': data})
>>> template = """
    <table>
        {% for row in data %}
            <tr>
            {% for item in row %}
                <td>{{ item }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
"""
>>> t = Template(template)
>>> print t.render(c)

    <table>

            <tr>

                <td>05/1/2014</td>

                <td>Brutus Brutus, Marc</td>

                <td>1234FRX</td>

                <td>192891478kjhda</td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td>05/2/2014</td>

                <td>Pepito Rudolf, Margarita</td>

                <td>2234FRX</td>

                <td>192891478kjhda</td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td>05/5/2014</td>

                <td>Patrick Linda, Judith</td>

                <td>5234FRX</td>

                <td>192891478kjhda</td>

            </tr>

    </table>
```